# Nissan Qashqai 2009 2.0 Accenta smoke and flame

Tags: engine, smoke, clutch-hydraulics

I had a new clutch installed in the car last week. 14kms later when I was entering the complex I noticed smoke coming from the engine. When I drove through the gate the clutch pedal went to the floor and twenty metres later I stopped the car when more smoke was coming out, and then flames. Can someone explain why this could possibly happen.

Comment: So, have you got the garage to collect it and check what they may have done wrong? It could be so many things.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is that there is a fluid leak between the clutch master cylinder and the slave cylinder. The fluid must be dripping on the exhaust, causing the smoke and flames.

Having a leak will cause a loss of fluid and hence the clutch pedal will go to the floor.